# jQuery mouseleave IE not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, mouseleave

So here is my script:

```
$(document).bind('mouseleave', function(event) {        
            // show popup
            console.log("you are about to leave the form!");
            //Get the A tag
            var id = $("#dialog");

            //Get the screen height and width
            var maskHeight = $(document).height();
            var maskWidth = $(window).width();

            //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
            $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

            //transition effect     
            $('#mask').fadeIn(250); 
            $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

            //Get the window height and width
            var winH = $(window).height();
            var winW = $(window).width();

            //Set the popup window to center
            $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
            $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

            //transition effect
            $(id).fadeIn(500);
    });
```

This code works great on all browsers BUT IE. The only time it seems to work is when I've activated the "developer tools" ... The actual bindable "mouseleave" trigger doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

---

It seems that IE does not like the "console.log" call to be in the method. Once I removed that reference, all worked.

Can someone enlighten me as to why that might be?

Comment: Kev, I appreciate the edit, but that's the answer... `console.log` is the issue within IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE only supports `console.log()` when Developer Tools are on. I think it's just a design decision they've made. You can try to overcome this in your code by defining your own logging function:

```
var log = function(s) {
  try {
    console.log(s);
  } catch (e) {
    alert(s); // If you want to see annoying popups.
  }           // If not, just leave this empty.
}
```